# cakephp condition can't list out the condition with upline value

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need some advice on this issue. I currently have a form that need my user to fill in. It is a drop down menu with conditions.

```
$groups = $this->User->Group->find('list', array ('conditions' => 'id < '.$upline['User']['group_id'] ));
```

So base on this selection, the user will face a problem that where no more left option on it.

Is it possible to do this : `id < '.$upline['User']['group_id'] => 1??`

My Second question.

```
$tgamemasters = $this->User->TgameMaster->find('list', array ('conditions' => 'id > '.$upline['User']['tgame_master_id'] ));
```

this is my another drop down menu option base on their upline choices.

while adding their downline, I have no problem on it. But when adding 3 downline, meaning the level 3 downline, the option is not given.

I don't know what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

```
'conditions' => 'id < '.$upline['User']['group_id']
```

should be

```
'conditions' => array( 'id < '.$upline['User']['group_id'] )
```

Also

```
'conditions' => 'id > '.$upline['User']['tgame_master_id']
```

should be

```
'conditions' => array( 'id > '.$upline['User']['tgame_master_id']  )
```